# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, webbrowser-control

I run a simple `C# WPF application` that uses a browser embedded in it. I have created a event when the browser navigates to the given url. But this bug comes during runtime:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred
>   in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The code is as follows,

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // Some initialisation
    webBrowser.Navigate(requiredUrl);
}

private void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Actions related to navigation
}
```

Its throwing the `Exception`.

Comment: Look at the InnerException of the TargetInvocationException - it will give you more details.

Comment: have you looked into the stacktrace or inner exception?

Comment: I have removed the exception after placing the   "webBrowser.Navigate(requiredUrl);" in the Window_Loaded event. But i dont know why?

Comment: The browser probably needs a valid window handle behind the scenes to do it's job, if moving the navigate to the loaded event worked you should answer your own question, it's probably going come up again with other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind,the problem is solved..

Move the webBrowser.Navigate(requiredUrl) to Windows_Loaded event.

```
       private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
         // Some code
          webBrowser.Navigate(requiredUrl);
       }
```

It's working fine now.

I think as Andy said the window needs a valid handle for the browser .

So it not working inside the MainWindow() function,as the handle for browser is not created in it.